Infinite access to microsoft graph Api refresh token for server side application
I have a server side application which needs to access  emails of all employees of my organization for statistics purpose (using apis) . I am going to  use  oauth to get the access of my employees outlook accounts by sending them oauth authorization links over mail. Is there a direct way to access my employees emails using admin account api's ? If I take individual consents from them, I want to make the refresh token life time infinite so that I dont need to send mails to my employees again and again for their oauth consent approval. Or there is any other way like running crons to update the refresh token for individual user to make its lifetime forever.
I have just tried google oauth playground to retieve emails for single user.

How about this: Get access without a user

You can follow the client credential flow outlined in the below documentation.
This allows you to generate a tenant-wide token and query without requiring user interaction for consent. This way, Admin needs to consent the application
Please refer to this documentation for detailed instructions: Microsoft Graph - Authentication using the v2.0 endpoint with client credentials.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow
